# How do I shift-copy multiple rows from one DOORS module to another DOORS module?

Tags: copy-paste, ibm-doors

## Background

In DOORS, you can select multiple rows of a module by holding down shift, then clicking on multiple rows. The text will then highlight red to signify that you have the rows selected.  You can then either copy, or copy with hierarchy. However, you cannot then paste the resulting rows into another module.

## Question

Is there a way to paste multiple selected rows from one DOORS module to another DOORS module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, This is possible. 
Use the inbuilt tool from DOORS to do this. TOOLS-->FUNCTIONS-->COPY OBJECTS
This tool is used from within your DOORS module that has the original objects.

Make sure you have your module open that you want to copy into.

The tool lets you select the target module, just make sure you have it open and have selected the position in the module you want the copied objects to be pasted.

Select the attributes you want to copy across. Use the Copy drop down menu to select how many objects your copying across, e.g. just  the selected ones, all the ones in the view, children, or entire module.

Linking - Your on your own, I haven't used this feature, in the copy tool.

Click OK / Apply.

Comment: You can copy and link multiple objects if they are part of a hierarchy. Drag the parent object from the source to the destination then select "Copy then link from Start" (or "Copy then link to Start") then "After (with hierarchy)" or "Below (with hierarchy)".

IMO, it's worth it to do it this way, even if you have to create a false hierarchy on the source side, then rearrange on the destination side.

Answer (score 1):

in a word: No
There  is no way to copy multiple objects, or even one object, from one module to another. The two modules would have to have exactly the same attributes and attribute types; no more, no less, even ones which are not populated in both. There is no way to guarantee this in the tool.
You could write a dxl to copy the information, say Object Text, from the one module into another, but I suspect that your question was more academic than practical in which case writing a dxl would not a prudent use of time.
Generally speaking, it is not a good idea to duplicate information in a database. the problem comes when one or both copies are changed, the difference will need to be reconciled. Better to use links to have the same data "appear" to be in both places.